# Set object param tag from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to embed video in object tag and I want to put the value of param from code-behind. But I'm not able to put the value from code-behind. Any idea where I'm getting wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
<object runat="server" id="object1">
    <param name="param1" value="www.youtube.com?id=123" runat="server" id="video1" />
    <param name="size" value="large" />
    <param name="category" value="wide" />
</object>
```

I want to change the value of `param1` from code-behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<object id="object1">
    <param name="<%= MyFunction() %>" value="www.youtube.com?id=123" id="video1" />
    <param name="size" value="large" />
    <param name="category" value="wide" />
</object>
```

In code behind, for example:

```
protected string MyFunction()
{
    return "param1Value";
}
```

Edit: removed both **runat="server"** - If those were only present for the purpose of using code behind to set the param, they are unnecessary for this solution.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can use inline expressions in a tag that is set to `runat="server"`. You'll need to use data-binding syntax instead, and then call `DataBind()` from your code-behind. Use this: `<%# MyFunction() %>` instead of `<%= MyFunction() %>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Dan.  The "runat=server" attributes are unnecessary/inappropriate to this solution

Comment: @Dan ...although DataBind() is unnecessary when the runat="server" tags are removed as shown in my revised answer

Comment: I guess u got me wrong ....but I can use this in the same way...I need to change the url in the value="" from code behind...thats what I meant by value of param1...I m sorry for confusion....But I guess I can use the same for that rite?

Comment: Yes, you can use this same technique to set the value of any attribute in your html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup I would think you can access it by id, such as:

```
video1.Attributes["value"] = "some value";
```

I've never used param tags on the server side though so there may be other issues at play...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without changing your  tag a bit. Check out the links below for some info on why this is the case:

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/aspnet/syntax/server-sideobjecttagsglobalasax.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1389622.aspx